# Covering set problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

All the references I can find to Covering Set appear to be algorithmic. Is there are any reference for the simple existential question ---

Suppose we have $k$ sets $X_1,…,X_k$ which are subsets of a ground set $X$ of size $n$. We know that $|X_i| \geq t$ for all $X_i$. We would like to find the smallest set $Y$ such that $Y \cap X_i \neq \emptyset$ for all $i$.

Given fixed values for $k, n, t$ what is the largest $Y$ which might be necessary to do this?

The greedy algorithm for constructing $Y$ is to add the element of $X$ to maximize the number of $X_i$ covered in each stage. Apparently this requires $|Y| = O(\frac{n}{t} \log k)$.

If I am not concerned with an algorithm for finding $Y$, only guaranteeing that it exists, is there any asymptotically better result possible?

Comment: (As JeffE said, this is a hitting set, not a covering set.) It seems that choosing a random hitting set large enough so that the expected number of sets missed is less than 1 also provides an upper bound of the form $O(n\log k/t)$, though surely the constant is worse.

Answer (score 3):

You've described the classical [hitting set](http://www.shannarasite.org/kb/kbse42.html) problem; it's NP-hard.

Moreover, given an oracle that determines whether there is a hitting set of size $k$ in polynomial time, it is easy to construct an algorithm that actually computes a hitting set of size $k$ in polynomial time plus a polynomial number of calls to the existence oracle.  (Details are left as a homework exercise.)  So the existence problem and the construction problem are polynomial-time equivalent.

Comment: This shows that the size is hard to determine, not that it is hard to approximate.  The question asked is whether O((n log k)/t) is the right order of magnitude, or is there something provably smaller.  If you have approximation results or evem an example (well, family of examples) where Y has that order of magnitude, that would answer the question.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseaman, 2012.04.14

Comment: As I said, I am not interested in algorithmics, only the existence of covering set.


Comment: David Harris, I respectfully disagree with your comment.  The existence of such a set is trivial; you are interested in good,  or at least better than obvious, upper bounds on the size of such a set.  A good part of algorithmics is in determining such bounds, and I think you will benefit most from approximation results, which JeffE might be able to provide.  Even if you don't want to see how the result is made, I think you will be interested in the taste, which to me means you care at least about the output of the algorithmics process.  Gerhard "But I've Been Wrong Before" Paseman, 2012.04.14

Comment: @Gerhard: My understanding is that David wants a good upper bound on the minimum hitting set as a function only of $k,t,n$, not as a function of the actual sets presented. David, is that right?

Comment: @Gerhard: I'm having trouble extracting your interpretation of the question from the written text.  I misinterpreted the last sentence as "I am not concerned with an algorithm for finding Y, only **for determining whether** it exists...".

Comment: Even though in his comment David mentioned covering set, I believe he meant hitting set, as he does in the question when he mentions Y.  Although he does not say t > 0, I think it is an interesting problem only if t > 0.  With these as my belief set, I think the existence of a hitting set is trivial, by forming Y from a favored choice of an element from each of the X sets. (I have seen no restrictions on Y, just a desire for minimizing the size of Y.)  Gerhard "But Wait, There is More" Paseman, 2012.04.15

Comment: Along with Brendan, I believe David wants a nice function f of the parameters t,k and n that will say that any instance that satisfies the parameters will have a minimal hitting set of size  at most f, and thus a hitting set of size exactly f. Nice is subjective, but for this problem we might agree that he wants one of better order than he stated with as few compositions and auxillary functions as possible, and I suspect he just cares about the order of f.  Although I may be wrong in thinking this, I think he wants approximation results.  Gerhard "And There Is Still More" Paseman, 2012.04.15



Comment: Even though he may want a function f (and not a proof that f works) that does the right thing, I think algorithmics will provide such an f.  I know that for some functions g, algorithmics is used to find examples which are not bounded by g (My creaky memory suggests bin packing, something like first fit increasing and some threshhold like 11/9 which was one of the first appproximation results I learned, probably around the time I took Math 221.) Provocative as my comment was, my intent was to clarify, and let David correct me if needed.  Gerhard "That's All For Right Now" Paseman, 2012.04.15

Comment: Now if we rewrite his question, provide a guessing parameter m, and ask about determining whether a hitting set Y of size at most m exists, that is an interesting and related question, and your remarks above would apply to estimating m.  Agaon, I think David's question is sufficiently different from this hypothetical rewrite.  In the comments above, just the existence of an unparameterized Y is mentioned, which for us should be easy to establish.  Gerhard "Now I Am Really Done" Paseman, 2012.04.15